# A lattice subgroup in $\Bbb R^n$ is discrete

Tags: general-topology, abelian-groups, integer-lattices

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n \in \Bbb R^n$ be linearly independent vectors and let $L = \{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \mid m_i \in \Bbb Z\}$, which is a free abelian group. I want to prove that it is discrete, so I would like to show that
$$B(\vec 0,r) \cap L = \{\overrightarrow 0\}$$
where $r = \min\limits_{1≤i≤n} \|v_i\|$ (with the usual euclidean norm and balls).

Assume that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \in L$ is non-zero and has norm $\|x\|<r$. If we assume that the $v_i$'s are orthonormal, then $\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n |m_i|^2<r=1 \implies m_i=0$ for all $i$ (since we have integers $m_i$).

How do I manage the other cases, where the $v_i$'s are not necessarily orthonormal?
Thank you!

Comment: A free abelian subgroup of $\Bbb R^n$ doesn't have to be discrete, see e.g. $A = \Bbb Z + \sqrt 2 \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb R^n$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Hence all norms are equivalent in $\mathbb R^n$.

For a vector $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$,
$$\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i \right\Vert_\infty = \sup\limits_i \vert \alpha_i \vert$$ is a norm. For $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \in L \setminus \{0\}$, you have
$$\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \right\Vert_\infty \ge 1$$

And as $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ is equivalent to $\Vert \cdot \Vert$, it exists $c > 0$ such that 
$$\Vert x \Vert \ge c \Vert x \Vert_\infty$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. Hence for all $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \in L \setminus \{0\}$
$$\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \right\Vert \ge c\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \right\Vert_\infty \ge c >0$$ which allows to conclude.

Comment: I really like this solution

Comment: Sorrry, what happens if $c<r$ ? For instance, if $c=r/2$, then $\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i \right\Vert≥c$ doesn't assure that $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i v_i$ is not is the ball $B(0,r)$.

Comment: We have $c= c \|u_i\|_{\infty} ≤ \|u_i\|$, i.e. $c≤r$.

Comment: For instance [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~kiming/lecture_notes/2005-2006-algebraic_number_theory/lattices+log_units.pdf) is a different argument.

Comment: $c$ is not whatever real. It is a real such that $\Vert x \Vert \ge c \Vert x \Vert_\infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Let $x \in L$ be such that $\|x\|<r$. Then I want to prove $x=0$. From your answer I know that if $x\neq 0$ then $\|x\|≥c$. This is not a contradiction with $\|x\|<r$, since $c≤r$. So how do I get a contradiction, if we assume $x \neq 0$? Could you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: What you assert is **wrong**. Take $v_1=(15,8), v_2=(-15,8)$. You have $\Vert v_1 \Vert = \Vert v_2 \Vert = 17$, so $r=17$. However, $v_1 + v_2=(0,16) \in L$ and $\Vert v_1 + v_2 \Vert =16 < r=17$, so $v_1+v_2 \in B(\vec 0,r) \cap L$. $r = \min\limits_{1≤i≤n} \|v_i\|$ cannot be used to prove that $B(\vec 0,r) \cap L = \{\overrightarrow 0\}$

Comment: Ah yes… Great counterexample ;-). I see that I should have written $B(\vec 0,c) \cap L = \{\overrightarrow 0\}$ with $c$ as in your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose by contradiction that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ there are non zero vectors $x^k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $m^k\in\mathbb{N}^n$ such that
$$x^k=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i^ke_i$$
and $|x^k|<\frac1k$. Then
$$\left|\frac{x^k}{|m^k|}\right|\leq|x^k|<\frac1k.$$
Now by compactness of the unit Euclidean sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is an accumulation point $m$ of $\frac{m^k}{|m^k|}$ and we obtain in the limit that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n m_ie_i=0$$
contradicting linear independence of the $e_i$'s.

PS The way you are trying to prove it is too strong (think of two very close vectors; then their difference is very small in norm).